# How can I implement a simple WHOIS proxy in Perl?

Tags: perl, proxy, whois, high-load

I have several [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) servers for which I want to have a single proxy. The proxy should forward requests to appropriate servers based on the data in the query. How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1 read the [RFC for WHOIS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912)
Step 2 implement a mock server with [Net::Server](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod)
Step 3 implement the proxy using your mock server and [Net::Whois::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Whois-Proxy/lib/Net/Whois/Proxy.pm) or some other WHOIS module

A quick scan of the RFC seems to say that it is just a simple text based protocol that expects one CRLF terminated line and then sends a blob of CRLF terminate lines and closes the socket.

Yep, it really looks that simple, given this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{
    package Whois;
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use parent 'Net::Server';

    sub process_request {
        my $request = <>;
        print "you sent me $request";
    }

}

Whois->run;
```

you can say

```
whois -h localhost -p 20203 foo.com
```

and get back

```
you sent me foo.com
```

Given the "high-load" tag, you will probably want to switch over to [`Net::Server::PreForkSimple`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server/PreForkSimple.pm) personality when you are done with testing.

And just because I was bored:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Whois {
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use parent 'Net::Server::PreFork';

    use Net::Whois::Raw;

    my %handler = (
        org => "whois.publicinterestregistry.net",
    );

    sub process_request {
        (my $request = <>) =~ s/[.]([^.]+)\x{0d}\x{0a}/.$1/;

        print exists $handler{$1} ?
            whois $request, $handler{$1} :
            "I don't know where to look for $request\r\n";
    }

}

Whois->run(
    user              => "nobody",
    group             => "nobody",
    port              => 43,
    min_servers       => 1,      #min number of children
    max_servers       => 10,     #max number of children
    min_spare_servers => 1,      #fork if we don't have this many waiting
    max_spare_servers => 5,      #kill if we have this many waiting
    max_requests      => 10_000, #num of requests before killing a child    
);
```

which when I run

```
sudo perl whois.pl
```

and then

```
whois -h localhost foo.org
```

gives us

```
NOTICE: Access to .ORG WHOIS information is provided to assist persons in
determining the contents of a domain name registration record in the Public Interest Registry
registry database. The data in this record is provided by Public Interest Registry
for informational purposes only, and Public Interest Registry does not guarantee its
accuracy.  This service is intended only for query-based access.  You agree
that you will use this data only for lawful purposes and that, under no
circumstances will you use this data to: (a) allow, enable, or otherwise
support the transmission by e-mail, telephone, or facsimile of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations to entities other than
the data recipient's own existing customers; or (b) enable high volume,
automated, electronic processes that send queries or data to the systems of
Registry Operator or any ICANN-Accredited Registrar, except as reasonably
necessary to register domain names or modify existing registrations.  All
rights reserved. Public Interest Registry reserves the right to modify these terms at any
time. By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.

Domain ID:D1608104-LROR
Domain Name:FOO.ORG
Created On:10-Jan-1995 05:00:00 UTC
Last Updated On:07-Mar-2011 00:26:43 UTC
Expiration Date:09-Jan-2012 05:00:00 UTC
Sponsoring Registrar:Fabulous.com Pty Ltd. (R133-LROR)
Status:CLIENT DELETE PROHIBITED
Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED
Registrant ID:fabwpp-000700385
Registrant Name:Domain Hostmaster, CustomerID : 85519846801225
Registrant Organization:Whois Privacy Services Pty Ltd
Registrant Street1:PO Box 923
Registrant Street2:
Registrant Street3:
Registrant City:Fortitude Valley
Registrant State/Province:QLD
Registrant Postal Code:4006
Registrant Country:AU
Registrant Phone:+61.730070090
Registrant Phone Ext.:
Registrant FAX:+61.730070091
Registrant FAX Ext.:
Registrant Email:85519846801225-959797@whoisprivacyservices.com.au
Admin ID:fabwpp-000700385
Admin Name:Domain Hostmaster, CustomerID : 85519846801225
Admin Organization:Whois Privacy Services Pty Ltd
Admin Street1:PO Box 923
Admin Street2:
Admin Street3:
Admin City:Fortitude Valley
Admin State/Province:QLD
Admin Postal Code:4006
Admin Country:AU
Admin Phone:+61.730070090
Admin Phone Ext.:
Admin FAX:+61.730070091
Admin FAX Ext.:
Admin Email:85519846801225-959797@whoisprivacyservices.com.au
Tech ID:fabwpp-000700385
Tech Name:Domain Hostmaster, CustomerID : 85519846801225
Tech Organization:Whois Privacy Services Pty Ltd
Tech Street1:PO Box 923
Tech Street2:
Tech Street3:
Tech City:Fortitude Valley
Tech State/Province:QLD
Tech Postal Code:4006
Tech Country:AU
Tech Phone:+61.730070090
Tech Phone Ext.:
Tech FAX:+61.730070091
Tech FAX Ext.:
Tech Email:85519846801225-959797@whoisprivacyservices.com.au
Name Server:NS1.HITFARM.COM
Name Server:NS2.HITFARM.COM
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
Name Server:
DNSSEC:Unsigned


whois.publicinterestregistry.net
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert on whois, but [Net::Whois::Proxy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aWhois%3a%3aProxy) would seem to be what you want.

Comment: I don't think so.  Despite the name, Net::Whois::Proxy appears to be a whois _client_, not a proxy at all.

Comment: A proxy server that takes whois requests and forwards them to the appropriate real server IS a client.  The only thing its doing as a server is listening for requests.

Comment: @Schwern: I need to proxy the original requests, not reconstruct them.

Comment: They can't be a whois proxy in the sense of an HTTP proxy since this protocol (`whois`) is a very simple one running on top of TCP/43 with absolutely no description of proxies. `Net::Whois::Proxy` is just a whois client. A real proxy would be a server and a client at the same time.